# snmp cisco switch oid for multiVlans

Tags: cisco, vlan

I'm using snmp to go through a switch and get some info.

i use:
for searching Names :
Oid: iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2

for searching a Single Vlan:
Oid: iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68.1.2.2.1.2

What i want is for multiple Vlans what is the oid.
Does anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

The Cisco OID referred to in your post will give you the VLAN-id associated on each interface on the device. For example snmpwalk yields following (so you can get all VLANs associated with the interfaces on the device)

```
# snmpwalk -v2c -c public 172.23.219.36 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.68.1.2.2.1.2 
..
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.68.1.2.2.1.2.436217344 = INTEGER: 101
```

Taking ifIndex from VLAN 101 one can find the associated interface

```
# snmpwalk -v2c -c public 172.23.219.36 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.436217344
..
IF-MIB::ifDescr.436217344 = STRING: Ethernet1/20
```

However if you are only interested in getting VLANs on the system you may want to consider looking at Q-BRIDGE-MIB (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4363). Any of these OIDs will get all the VLANs on the system whether associated with an interface or not via Q-BRIDGE MIB (dot1qFdbTable)

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 172.23.219.36 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.2.1.1.2.1 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.2.1.1.2.101 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.2.1.1.2.201 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.2.1.1.2.301 = Counter32: 0
```